# Painter Chain LWUIT

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I am doing a chain painter it paints 2 layers and the third one  should pressed or move the touch screen to be appeared what should I do to make it appear without press or move the screen the code is :

```
Painter[] layers = new Painter[3];
         layers[0] = new Painter() {

        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            try {
                g.drawImage(Image.createImage("/Classic.png"), 100, 40);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
       layers[1] = new Painter() {

        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            g.setColor(0xff0000);
            g.drawLine(10, 30, 60, 60);
            g.drawLine(10, 60, 60, 30);
        }
    };
    layers[2] = new Painter() {

        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            g.setColor(0xffffff);

            g.drawString("500 LE", 20, 35);
            g.drawString("300 LE", 20, 65);
        }
    };





    PainterChain chainLayers = new PainterChain(layers);
    setGlassPane(chainLayers);
```

Comment: "_third one should pressed or move the touch screen to be appeared_" please elaborate ? Should this be done on an event or on some timer ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a painter chain? You "know in advance" all of the painters that would be installed on a component just call the or just unify them.

There is no painter to represent component state, component state is represented via style/UIID and the default internal painter. You should probably limit yourself to using these elements.